# Как изменить BackGround Color вкладки game в Unity

Tags: unity3d

Нужно изменить bg color, так-как в проекте слишком много темных цветов и оно все сливается невозможно работать!

Интернет облазил, в редакторе все про тыкал нашел только как поменять цвет фона в Scene Но это не подходит[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Edit` → `Preferences` → `Colors`

Comment: @Арман Там только можно поменять цвет сцены, а мне нужно вкладки game!

Comment: Все цвета там. Если там нет такого цвета значит возможность поменять этот цвет нету

Comment: Можно закрыть область расширив иерархию и инспектор =D Или разместить `Game` и `Scene`, не как вкладки, а разбить область. Просто организуйте пространство редактора иначе.

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужен параметр Background в камере
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Старайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы (кнопка [edit]).